# UI updating command in View Model (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

I'm making a WPF application on MVVM pattern, where the user clicks the items of a tree (hyperlinks consisting of color names, the name text having the respective foreground) to **change the background of the whole window.** I am doing this through a relay command, but the UI is not acceptable in the View Model, where I am writing the command.

**The tree with Color Names in XAML:**

```
<TreeView Name="tree" ItemSource="{Binding colorList, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemSource={Binding Children}>
             <TextBlock><Hyperlink Command={Binding ColorChangerCommand} Foreground={Binding Foreground} TextDecorations="None"><TextBlock Text={Binding Name}/></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 <TreeView>
```

**The Command in my View Model:**

```
public RelayCommand ColorChangerCommand{ get; set;}

public TreeViewModel() //Constructor of the View Model
{
   ColorChangerCommand= new RelayCommand(ChangeColor);
}

public void ChangeColor(object sender)
{
  this.Background= (sender as TreeViewItem).Foreground;
}
```

The command was working fine in simple code-behind, but now not in the View Model. Help please?

Comment: Can you show your binding statement . in Xaml you are binding foregorund but in ViewModel property is named as Background

Comment: @PraveenM The foreground in Xaml is just simply the foreground of the text that has to be shown. For Example, the first item is "RED" with Red color as it's foreground.
In the command in ViewModel, I'm getting the foreground of the clicked item, as setting it as the background of the window. For Example, If RED is clicked, the background of the Window becomes Red too.

Comment: when using a commands the object that you get in your ChangeColor-function is not the sender. This only works in events! What you should do is take a look at XAML triggers so you can solve your issue the way it was intended to be handled in WPF

Comment: I agree that this is a bit of a predicament that you're in, but consider following: Return a string from your view model i.e colour you want for the foreground and use a converter in UI to create a `SolidColorBrush`. Hope this helps

Comment: There should be a view model item class that represents the data of an individual TreeViewItem. That class should have a Color or Brush property for the Background color, which is modified by the command. In the TreeView's ItemContainerStyle, bind the TreeViewItem's Background to this view model property.

Comment: Why is this a treeview rather than a listbox? How do you decide which colours?

Comment: @Andy I was just practicing tree view. The colors are just randomly chosen shades of rgb

Comment: @Clemens Yes, there is a class for that. The thing is, the command does not access UI elements in the view model, so I can't change the background there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.Background` refers to the `Background` property of your view model provided that the `ChangeColor` method belongs to the view model class. For the window's background to change, you need to bind it to the `Background` property of the view model and raise an event to tell the UI to update. This requires your view model to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public RelayCommand ColorChangerCommand { get; set; }

    public TreeViewModel() //Constructor of the View Model
    {
        ColorChangerCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeColor);
    }

    public void ChangeColor(object sender)
    {
        this.Background = (sender as TreeViewItem).Foreground;
    }

    private Brush background= Brushes.White;
    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return background; }
        set { Background = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(Background); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window .... Background="{Binding Background}" />
```

You also need to set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of your view model class and bind the `Command` property of the `Hyperlink` like this:

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.ColorChangerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
           Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" TextDecorations="None">
```

Comment: `public void ChangeColor(object sender)
    {
        this.Background = (sender as TreeViewItem).Foreground;
    }
`  The sender is returning null here

Comment: @BellaSwan: Bind the `CommandParameter` of the `Hyperlink` to the `TreeViewItem`: `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"`.

Comment: Now the background is going black on clicking every item, instead of changing to the respective color. :(

Comment: What is the "respective color", i.e. where do you set the `Foreground` colour of the `TreeViewItem`? Does the binding work?

Comment: Yes, it does. When I created the list for the tree view items, I added the foreground and the name, then bound it in the XAML. For example, the word RED is being shown in red color. So when I click on it, being the sender, shouldn't it give it's foreground color to the Background, which is red?

Comment: No, because you set the `Foreground` of the `Hyperlink` and not the `TreeViewItem`. Try to change `sender as TreeViewItem` to `sender as Hyperlink` in your view model and bind the `CommandParameter` to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` in your XAML.

Comment: The word Hyperlink is not being allowed as a sender in the view model

Comment: `Hyperlink` is a type. Either add `using System.Windows.Documents;` on top or use a fully qualified type name: `sender as System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it via ViewModel. UI belongs to the View. Use a behavior for it.

If you bind `ForwardedColor` to any other UI control, then you will change the bound property of this control, so you can easily manage it in XAML.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
<TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Aquamarine">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ForwardForegroundOnClick  ForwardedColor="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>

public class ForwardForegroundOnClick : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    public Brush ForwardedColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForwardedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForwardedColorProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForwardedColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ForwardedColor), typeof(Brush), typeof(ForwardForegroundOnClick), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ForwardedColor = AssociatedObject.Foreground;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;

        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```